# How to use keys in c# to navigate through a console application?

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and I'm trying to creat a small console application. In this application I want to implement a **Welcome Screen** in which the user would be greated and asked to press a key like *Escape* to exit or *Enter* to continue the application **menu**.

I'm wondering if there's a way to display only the **menu** after the user wants to press *Enter* key.
I would be happy for any help. Thank you.

Here's the example of what I'm trying to do:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ConsoleKeyInfo key;

            Console.WriteLine("Welcome! \n\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to continue or ESC to quit.");

            while (true)
            {
                key = Console.ReadKey(true);

                if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
                {
                    Menu menu = new Menu();
                    menu.demo();
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by menu?

Comment: It would be a class that with display functionalities of my application, something like that:

Comment: 1. Do something, 2. Do something else

Comment: So you want to display only the menu and clear the rest? Console.Clear() is what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, I just want to clear the rest and open the menu object.

Comment: @JarekDanielak thanks a lot, that was what I neded!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's what you mean

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ConsoleKeyInfo key;
        bool isEnter = true;
        while (isEnter)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("----------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome! \n");
            Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to continue or ESC to quit.");
            key = Console.ReadKey(true);

            if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
            {
                isEnter = false;
                break;
            }
            else if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
            {

                Console.Clear();
                Menu menu = new Menu();
                menu.demo();
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for help, bro. Console.clear was what i neded =).

Comment: update code , you must use Console.Clear(); for clear console